# In a jinja2 template, how do i check if an element in a mongo database is one of three possible strings?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid, jinja2

My template has if/else functionality to handle displaying buttons on a page, I've managed to add an elif statement that displays the buttons only if an element in a mongo database is not one of three values. I'm trying to clean this up as the elif appears four times across two jinja2 templates. My code which works now looks like this:

```
{% elif (
   ('string1' not in database.category) and ('string2' not in database.category) and
   ('string3' not in database.category)) %}
```

I've tried declaring a tuple and doing a:

```
{% set hidebuttons = ['string1' , 'string2' , 'string3'] %} //sets tuple
{% elif not database.category in hidebuttons %} // checks if value not in tuple
```

and plenty of other methods to make this work but every time I reload the web page i keep seeing the buttons when i shouldn't be. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be in your view, not your template.  If you need to do the query in more then one place, you can create a utility function that gets the results you need, then in your views, you can call the function and pass the data as context to your templates

if you're using a view_config decorator to render template, it could be something like:

```
@view_config(renderer='templates/foo.pt')
def my_view(request):
    show_buttons = logic_to_determine_should_buttons_be_shown()
    return {'show_buttons': show_buttons }


# your template
{% if show_buttons %}
  show buttons
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can I throw that 'show_buttons = logic_to_determine_buttons()' bit in the view which renders the parent page if the actual template where the elif goes is a child template?

Comment: @ComputerScienceN00b yes, i believe so